# Globally writable files and user-based process jailing

Tags: security, users, jails

I want to be able to generically pick a certain executable (potentially malicious) `x` and run it (from an admin account) with write access restricted to certain directories (dynamically deduced) `"${dirs[@]}"`.

The executable should have access to whatever is globally accessible on the system.

I figured I could use simple user-switching and have a dedicated, stateless system user `foreveralone`, for running theses executables.

Whenever I would want to run `x` with these restrictions, I would, `flock` a lock file, `chown -R foreveralone:foreveralone -- "${dirs[@]}"` and then do `sudo -u foreveralone -g foreveralone $PWD/x`.

After that, I would `chown` the write directories to someone else, so that `foreveralone` would have no persistent files on the filesystem.
I figure I would also need to clean up up global write directories (e.g., `/tmp, /dev/shm`) from `foreveralone`s files.

My questions are:

1. Is this a feasible and secure mechanism for jailing processes, given a standardly setup *nix system?
2. What exactly are the standard globally writable places and files on a a standardly setup *nix?
3. How can I find them better than with something like

   sudo -u foreveralone -g foreveralone  find /  ! -type l -writable 2>/dev/null | grep -v '^/proc'

   (My `find` game is very weak. `/proc/$pid` appears to have lots of files that appear writable but, in fact aren't so I'm skipping those (I wonder what's up with that)).

Anyway, on my system, 3. returns (filtered to show filetypes):

```
  character special file    /dev/full
  character special file    /dev/fuse
  character special file    /dev/net/tun
  character special file    /dev/null
  character special file    /dev/ptmx
  character special file    /dev/random
  character special file    /dev/tty
  character special file    /dev/urandom
  character special file    /dev/zero
  character special file    /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/.null
  directory /run/lock
  directory /run/shm
  directory /tmp
  directory /tmp/.ICE-unix
  directory /tmp/.X11-unix
  directory /var/local/dumps
  directory /var/mail
  directory /var/spool/samba
  directory /var/tmp
  regular empty file    /run/sendmail/mta/smsocket
  regular empty file    /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/.access
  socket    /dev/log
  socket    /run/acpid.socket
  socket    /run/avahi-daemon/socket
  socket    /run/cups/cups.sock
  socket    /run/dbus/system_bus_socket
  socket    /run/gdm_socket
  socket    /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  socket    /run/samba/nmbd/unexpected
  socket    /run/sdp
  socket    /tmp/.ICE-unix/2537
  socket    /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
  socket    /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
```

4. Is there a better (simpler/more flexible solution to this)

In my particualar case, `x` would be a potentially malicious build script which should run without writing to the wrong places or reading things that aren't globally readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First sorry for my bad english. Lets show something for you using only unix concepts, cause i think it can help (or maybe not).

Imagine that i want that the executable nano can be executed by every users, but must never run as the user that call its executable, but with a limited environment, with access to edit the apache configuration only or files in certain groups, in other words i want nano to be executed like a linux service limited to a specific virtual user privileges.

1- First i will create the user nano and disable its login:

```
useradd nano -d /var/nano
mkdir /var/nano 
chown -R nano:nano /var/nano
passwd -l nano
```

2- Lets force nano to run as user nano(for example if root call nano it must run as nano and not by root)

```
chown nano:nano /usr/bin/nano
chmod a+s /usr/bin/nano
```

Now +s means, that nano will run as the owner and not by who called it.

3- Call nano with root for a test:

```
#nano
#ps aux | grep nano
nano      3399  0.0  0.0  13828  3840 pts/0    S+   08:48   0:00 nano
```

Beautiful! Nano now run as user nano not depending in what user i logged with.

4- So what now? I want nano to edit the files at /var/www/apache2

```
chgrp -R www-data /var/www/ (yes i now that is unnecessary in Debian if the group are respected)
chmod -R g+rw /var/www 
adduser nano www-data
```

5- What more?

You will note that every user now can use nano (or a special copy of it "nano-special" ;-) to edit /var/www files, so what if you want that only users in group nano can do that?

Simple remove other privileges to execute it:

```
chmod o-x /usr/bin/nano
```

And add the users to the group nano

```
adduser myuser1 nano
```

Comment: It  doesn't actually answer my question but it's a nice example. I think this approach of traditional user-space-based jailing is feasible and that I just need to clean up the globally writable directories to clean up. Maybe I'll upgrade  to AppArmor or something later, but I'd rather not. Thanks for the time to make the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I gived +1 to you. I think you can jail your program using this method and put the user of the program at the groups that have access to the devices you want, giving +w permission in the files it will need to access to the group.